# Efficient polynomial ring multiplication with coefficients in GF(2^s)

Tags: implementation

Is there something similar (or an other efficient approach) to the **NTT** for the multiplication of polynomials in polynomial rings modulo $X^{2^n} + 1$ with coefficients in $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ with $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n+1}}$, but instead for polynomial rings with coefficients in $\operatorname{GF}(2^s)$?

Comment: Not NTT, but you might be interested to see how BearSSL computes $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ arithmetic for GHASH in software: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66462

Comment: On characteristic 2 additive FFTs serve this purpose. Chapter 3 of [Mateer's thesis](https://cr.yp.to/f2mult/mateer-thesis.pdf) has a number of these, and several others have been discovered since then.

Comment: FFT-based GHASH with high bulk throughput (but also high setup overhead): https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/729

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at all this content